# unparsebale date exception java

Tags: java, date

i want to format this type of date : `Sun Feb 14 12:12:47 GMT+05:30 2016`

into `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);`

this is what i tried:

```
try {

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
        Locale.ENGLISH);

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);



Date pasta = sdf.parse(notesTimeStampArray.get(i));

String  newDate =  pasta.toString();

Date past = format.parse(newDate);


Date now = new Date();

Toast.makeText(TabFragment2.context, "inside 1 success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}catch (Exception e){


Toast.makeText(TabFragment2.context, "error : " +e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

but am not succeeding,  anyone can correct me ? it'll so helpful for me

Comment: `String newDate = pasta.toString();`?

Comment: hey , pasta is a date which is formatted from string then am trying to format it again in the second format , sorry for confusing variable name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `format` instead of parse to format the date returned from the first date format operation

```
String dateString = format.format(pasta);
```

Comment: hey Reimseus let me try this